# Currency not shown in Facebook Product Catalog (WooCommerce Plugin)

Tags: wordpress, facebook, woocommerce, product-catalog

I'm using the Facebooks's plugin for WooCommerce to upload a datafeed to a Product Catalog. However, at my Facebook shop page the currency is not shown - only the price amount.

[image]

When I log in to Facebook Business Manager and try to edit a product in this catalog, I see the currency. So clearly, the currency is stored.
[image]

If I go to the settings for my product datafeed, the currency is also set.

Is there something I'm missing here?
I'm only having one currency.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not the place for software support handling… You should contact plugin authors support pages instead as this seems a bug like.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I have contacted Facebook, but didn't get that much help from there. That's why I wanted to turn here to see if someone had experienced this and know how to get this to work (if possible).

Comment: @moviaa I tried [this free plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/webtoffee-product-feed/) for this purpose. It provides on-demand synching woocommerce products to selected facebook catalogs and works fine.